# Python - Using APIs

Tags: python, ip, openweathermap

I have recently been attempting to code a gelocation-based weather forecasting system using **tkinter and pycharm edu**. The project has been going well for the most part, though when it came to coding my last part, I have run into some difficulties.

My program includes a function that should detect the location of the user, and display weather results akin to this information. For this, I used an API called 'ipBase,' and got the code I have used from a website (as I am largely inexperienced with coding of this magnitude). I had assumed it would work, though using my program will always create an error whenever I attempt to use the button/function to get locational weather. It keeps producing an error saying **KeyError: 'name'**

This is the function. The API for the weather that I have used is **Open Weather**, the variables ipURL and weather_URL refer to the endpoints for the APIs from their respective websites.

Any feedback as to why this function can not work would be massively appreciated!

```
def get_location_weather():
    query_params = {
        "apiKey": api_Lkey
    }
    response = requests.get(ipURL, params=query_params)
    city_name = response.json()["data"]["location"]["city"]["name"]

    weather_query_params = {
        'q': city_name,
        'appid': api_Wkey,
        'units': 'metric'
    }
    response = requests.get(
        weather_URL, params=weather_query_params)
    weather_data = response.json()

    # Display weather data
    weather_label.config(text=f"{weather_data['name']}: {weather_data['main']['temp']}°C")
```

I've tried looking at multiple websites and even using my own knowledge, but it will refuse to work.

Comment: `response.json()["data"]["location"]["city"]` does not contain a key "name".  It's that simple.  Why were you expecting that key to exist?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the API response does not contain the 'name' key like in **city_name = response.json()["data"]["location"]["city"]["name"]**.Here you are accessing 'name' inside 'city'.Check it once.
For this please first print response and ensure your key name properly.